# VBA methods htmlDoc.getElementBy* return Nothing

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

Greetings to everyone.

---

#### GOAL

I want to open [flashscore.com](https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/) and get data related to soccer matches.
I want all the matches of this season, so the link "Show more matches" will have to be clicked one or more times.

---

#### RESTRICTIONS

- I need to do this using VBA
- This site does not support Internet Explorer
- I cannot install anything on the pc that will be used, so Selenium is turned down as an option

Bearing in mind all of the above, the only option left, seems to be the `Microsoft XML, v6.0` library.

---

#### WHAT I 'VE TRIED

I 've read several possible duplicates to this post and tried their solutions, but nothing seemed to help so far.
Here is the code with comments explaining every situation:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Matches()
'REFERENCE TO Microsoft XML, v6.0
Dim httpReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim eleCol As Object
Dim ele As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
    
'Open site and get html. In comments:things proposed by others but seemed to make no change.
    httpReq.Open "GET", "https://www.flashscore.com/football/england/premier-league-2019-2020/results/"
    'httpReq.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    httpReq.send
    Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    doc.body.innerHTML = httpReq.responseText
    'doc.body.innerHTML = httpReq.responseBody


'Tried to get the div containing the first match:
    Set ele = doc.getElementById("g_1_2JDks1o7") '--> returns nothing

'Tried to get the "Show more matches" link:
    Set ele = doc.getElementsByClassName("event__more")(0) '--> returns nothing

'Tried to get the first ancestor that has an id:
    Set ele = doc.getElementById("live-table") '--> returns nothing


'Tried to get all <a> elements and then narrow them down till I find the "Show more matches" link:
    Set eleCol = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each ele In eleCol
        If ele.href Like "*[#]*" And ele.innerText = "Show more matches" Then 
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ele
    ele.Click '--> I get the "Show more matches" link, but nothing seems to change
'Someone suggested firing onclick event.
    ele.FireEvent "onclick" '--> did nothing


'Some people suggested waiting.
'So I tried this:
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop While doc.readyState = "loading"
    If doc.readyState <> "complete" Then GoTo ERROR_END
    Set doc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    doc.body.innerHTML = httpReq.responseText
'and the Delay_Code_By function below,
    Set ele = doc.getElementById("live-table") '--> but still returns nothing


'Some people suggested looping, so the document gets loaded first.
    Do: Set ele = doc.getElementById("live-table"): DoEvents: Loop While ele Is Nothing '--> resulted to infinite loop.
    Do: Set eleCol = doc.getElementsByClassName("event__more"): DoEvents: Loop Until eleCol.Length > 0 '--> resulted to infinite loop.


'This block extracts html in a txt file in desktop, to help me see it, as it is at runtime.
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
'    Dim txtFile As Scripting.TextStream
'    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
'    Set txtFile = fso.OpenTextFile(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\output.txt", 2, True, TristateTrue)
'    txtFile.Write httpReq.responseText
'    txtFile.Close
'    Set txtFile = Nothing
'    Set fso = Nothing
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Inside the txt file I found html code that onclick calls some kind of function:

'Tried to call this function:
    doc.parentWindow.execScript "document.body.classList.toggle('loading', true);", "JScript" '--> throws automation error (probably there's some error with my syntax).

'I also tried to call this function:
    doc.parentWindow.execScript "function(){return cjs.Api.loader.get('cjs').call(function(_cjs){loadMoreGames(_cjs);});};" '--> which did not throw error but did nothing.


    Exit Sub
ERROR_END:
    MsgBox "error"
End Sub


Public Sub Delay_Code_By(seconds As Integer)
Dim endTime As Date
    endTime = DateAdd("s", seconds, Now)
    Do While Now < endTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

---

#### QUESTIONS

1. If there is any other option that I'm missing, other than using `Microsoft XML, v6.0` library, please tell me to try it.
2. As far as I understand the problem is that the elements I'm trying to get are not present the moment I try to get them. If I am correct, can anyone please explain me why is this happening and a possible workaround this one? If I am wrong please point me to the right direction.Thank you.

#### UPDATE

I'm posting this screenshot based on @QHarr 's comment about watching the network/xhr tab.
[image: network xhr tab]

Comment: If scraping is allowed see if you can find an xhr in the network tab which is used to update the page with the required content. Click the show more and see what is generated in the network tab.

Comment: I did what you proposed and something is generated indeed. Can you please explain me shortly what is being done? I 'll update the question with a screenshot to see exactly.

Comment: If the page is dynamically updated then you may see those updates in the network tab and potentially find your data in one of those additional requests.